# How to separate my coding with functions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to separate the following code with a function:

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
myWebRequest.Accept = "image/*";
myWebRequest.Method = "GET";
```

And then following with another function:

```
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
Response.Clear();

Stream receiveStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

If like this two functions separated, then how can I use the `myWebRequest` variable from the first function into secondly function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply let your first method return the newly created `HttpWebRequest`:

```
public HttpWebRequest CreateRequest()
{
    HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    myWebRequest.Accept = "image/*";
    myWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    return request;
}
```

Now let your second method call it in order to get the request:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)CreateRequest().GetResponse(); 
    Response.Clear();

    Stream receiveStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
}
```